# Maximum density of a set without a fixed pattern

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

Consider a finite set $S$ of nonnegative integers.

What is the maximum natural density of an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ which does not contain any translation of $S$?

Of course, this will depend on $S$, but maybe there is a simple algorithm or characterization.
I am also interested about the same question in $\mathbb{Z}^k$.

Have the above questions been researched in any form? I didn't come up with a search query which returns anything.

Comment: Have you tried searching in terms of 2-letter words rather than integers? Do you know the density of the greedy (translation-free) set?

Comment: If you are okay with dilates of $S$, then this sounds like a Furstenberg-Katznelson-Weiss over the integers, which has been studied by Akos Magyar (see, for example, here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1229530283 ).

Maybe Magyar has studied undilated problem as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is equivalent to finding the minimum density of a covering of $\mathbb{Z}$ by translations of $-S$. This problem has been studied for the integers and also for other groups; see for example

Wolfgang M. Schmidt and David M. Tuller, Covering and packing in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$,
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2Fs00605-009-0099-x

Béla Bollobás, Svante Janson and Oliver Riordan, On covering by translates of a set,
https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20346

Comment: Thank you! Searching for the first paper yields also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137219/is-this-a-known-combinatorial-problem.